# How to get text value from XML in Flutter

Tags: flutter, xml-parsing

I would like to know how to get the text value from an XML document in flutter. I know to use the XML dart library already just having trouble when it comes to parsing the variables. 
For example:
The XML line: Bob
In my current parsing set up returns: (Bob)
How do I do it without the brackets?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Explain your current parsing setup for example.

Comment: if I get you correctly, you mean you want to use `strings.xml` file value in your Flutter `lib.dart` file?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad not quite, I am trying to parse XML from an API. I am already successfully downloading the XML I just don't understand how to parse it to strings or variables.

Comment: You may want to use `JSON`, it is easier to parse than `XML` in Flutter.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Yeah, wish I could. I am using a 3rd party API and am unable to ask for a change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Instead of converting XML to JSON you can use the Flutter XML package (https://pub.dev/packages/xml)

Example:

```
XmlDocument xml = XmlDocument.parse('''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Results>
    <Person>
        <Name>Joe Blogs</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Alexander Hamilton</Name>
        <Age>28</Age>
    </Person>
</Results>
''');

print(xml.getElement("Results")
    .firstElementChild.getElement("Person").getElement("Name").text);
print(xml.getElement("Results")
    .firstElementChild.getElement("Person").getElement("Age").text);
```

Output:

```
Joe Blogs
21
```

I would recommend this updated method as converting to JSON can incorrectly parse causing data loss.

---

**OLD VERSION**:

I managed to get around my issue with inspiration from @CopsOnRoad.

I parsed the XML data returned from the API to a JSON array using the Flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json

And then managed to display it with arrays.

Example:

```
String xmlString = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "rootDtd" "dtd/root.dtd">
<root>
    <element1>Child 1</element1>
    <element2>Child 2</element2>
    <element3>Child 3</element3>
    <element4>Child 4</element4>
    <element5>Child 5</element5>
    <element6>Child 6</element6>
    <element7>Child 6</element7>
</root>
''';
          Xml2Json xml2json = new Xml2Json();

          xml2json.parse(xmlString);
          var json = xml2json
              .toParker(); // the only method that worked for my XML type.

          print(json);
          var response = jsonDecode(json);
          print(response);
        } catch (JSONException) {}
```

Comment: Hi, how you get only the content inside the master tag (like a news) and save in the model?

Comment: Hi @FilipeOS! I would recommend using the updated option now. Using the new option you can just do xml.getElement("MASTER_TAG").children to get all elements inside the master tag. Hope this helps, even though its a few years late!

Comment: @blowonthepi thanks mate, it works perfectly what I needed, but a small problem occurs. When I see the list of all tags including data, in an alternative index like 0 has no value but create an empty index & index 1 has value and same goes for all the list, some index has no values but some index has values. What is the reason behind this? I'll share my list output if you say so. Btw this is the best solution, I must recommend this.

Comment: @AsimZubair could you give a segment of the output and a segment of the input?

Comment: XML as an Input https://pasteboard.co/K0pKbGD.png and its list output is this https://pasteboard.co/K0pLcVk.png. Index [0,2,4,6] is empty